# accessing restlet from programming languages different than java

Tags: java, programming-languages, binding, restlet

if im using restlet as an API, can I access it from client PCs using programming langages other than java ? and do I need language binding ? or how could this be done ? I don't have experience in this so can you please provide good explanation  ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST architectures are independent from any language. This means that they can be produce and consume by any language / technology and the sent data format can be specified using the Content-Type header. Moreover the possible expected data format for responses can be "configured" using content negociation (headers Accept).

You can even interact with RESTful applications with simple / low level client like RestClient (http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/). The tool allows you specifying hints for the HTTP request.

You can also notice that some works are done at the moment to make available a JavaScript version of Restlet. See the following page for more details: http://wiki.restlet.org/developers/172-restlet/g1/368-restlet.html. A very first version of the Restlet client support is usable within browser and node.js.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Restlet framework to provide a RESTful API. [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) itself is a software architecture style and language independent.

Basically any client capable of generating [HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) requests and deserializing the data you return (JSON, XML, HTML etc.) should be able to access your API.

There are also a lot of client libraries for different languages that make using RESTful services more easy. The [implementing REST](http://code.google.com/p/implementing-rest/) project has more information about these.